# Demonstrate series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

i have this series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^m{a^n}$$

and I need a mathematical demonstration

anyone know the name of the series?

Comment: Finite geometric series.

Comment: @Lena: You selected a wrong answer.  André's comment is correct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Convergent Geometric series if $-1<a<1$.
Divergent Geometric series if $a<-1$ or $a>1$

Comment: No, it is a finite geometric series.